# Authentication Error When connect to Analysis Services Database by Power Query

Tags: authentication, ssis, powerquery, power-bi-report-server, analysisservices

I'm having a trouble when trying to connect to the power bi server/ Analysis Services in order to crawl data and doing the ETL process with SSIS. The tool I used is Power Query Connection in SSIS. My login was okay until one day, it appears as:

> AnalysisServices: Unable to obtain authentication token using the
> credentials provided. If your Active Directory tenant administrator
> has configured Multi-Factor Authentication or if your account is a
> Microsoft Account, please remove the user name and password from the
> connection string, and then retry. You should then be prompted to
> enter your credentials. (Microsoft.MashupEngine)

However, I still can login this Analysis Services with the same credentials by SSMS.
Hope I am able to recieve your answers asap.
Thanks

I try login with this Analysis Services by SSMS and it's ok, but power query connection still shows that error